# Why is exit_code not correct at end of script?

Tags: ksh

Asked this in google groups, but I see similar questions previously asked here so I ask     here also.
   This would seem to be a scoping question, but the variable is global as far as I can tell.

Tallied exit code is always zero.

Thanks.

```
ksh -c "exit_code=0;
 # Get a list of sql files and interate through them to do certain work on a DB.
 find ./sql_email_reports -maxdepth 1 -type f -print | while read line;
 do echo \"Report = \" \${line};

   #Now do some sql work on a DB based on the sql file as given by $line. 
       #and if the work to the DB fails for some reason, send back a return code                     greater than zero.
   rc=\$?;

   # Test the incrementation of exit_code by setting rc, which should increment   exit_code for every file found in directory.
   rc=1

   echo \"rc = \" \${rc};
   (( exit_code+=rc ));
   echo \"Exit Code =\" \${exit_code};

 done;


enter code here
 # For some reason, the tallied exit_code is not what it is within the while loop, it is still zero 

 echo \"Tallied exit_code = \" \${exit_code};
 (( exit_code > 0 )) && exit 1;
 exit 0;"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `while` loop runs in a subshell, so the variable manipulations are not visible to the parent.

This is a FAQ.  http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/024 is aimed at Bash users, but generally applies to `ksh` and POSIX shell as well.

Comment: Oh heck, how the heck do I fix that?

Answer (score 0):

You can eliminate the pipeline by using a glob instead of `find`:

```
exit_code=0
for f in ./sql_email_reports/*; do
    [ -f "$f" ] || continue  # -type f
    f=${f##*/}               # Strip leading path, leaving the base name
    rc=1
    echo "rc=$rc"
    (( exit_code += rc ))
    echo "Exit Code = $exit_code"
done

echo "Tallied exit_code = $exit_code"
(( exit_code > 0 )) && exit 1
exit 0
```

Comment: I did try a for loop which seemed to give the exit_code back, but the way I did it, if there were two or more files in the directory, it would list all the files in the one $f variable. But I can try your suggestion. Thanks to you too.